# My Nexus One cannot connect to Wi-Fi being broadcast by a Windows 7 laptop

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, nexus-one, windows

My Android (Google HTC Nexus One) is not detecting Wi-Fi being broadcast by my Windows 7 laptop. However, my iPhone can detect the laptop's network. Why is that?

Is there any solution for connecting my Nexus One?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're trying to broadcast a wireless signal using your laptop so that your mobile devices can connect to it. If you set this up via the standard Windows 7 networking tools it would have created an ad-hoc network, and Android does not support ad-hoc connections out-of-the-box.

You can, however, use a "softAP" (that is - software access point) to broadcast a signal as an AP instead of in ad-hoc mode. [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/windows.html) works great for me, and I would recommend giving it a try. A list of their supported wireless cards can be found [here](http://www.connectify.me/support/index.php?act=article&code=view&id=13).

Additionally, you can try to "enable" ad-hoc networking on the Nexus One using the steps described in [this forum thread](http://android.modaco.com/content/google-nexus-one-nexusone-modaco-com/300596/nexus-one-connect-to-ad-hoc-wifi/). These steps will require that you have rooted your device, however.

Comment: I have tried Connectify too but my iphone and android device was not opening any website, while they were connected with connectify. I'm getting the message device "connecting" all the time in connectify but not "connected". for both iphone and android

Comment: @Jitendra: Hm, I suppose it could be a firewall issue or your card might not be fully supported. I'd also check to make sure the correct device is selected since I think it defaults to re-broadcasting the wifi signal. You can see that if you right click the tray icon and select `Show All Options`.

Comment: @Jitendra: Oh, so they never fully connect to Connectify, then?

Comment: They detect the wi-fi signal but unable to connect to internet

Comment: @Jitendra: I'm not entirely sure how to troubleshoot that, to be honest. Connectify "just worked (TM)" when I installed it, and I use it without issue almost every day. They have a [support page](http://www.connectify.me/support/index.php?act=kb) that you could try, or maybe it would make for a good question on [Super User](http://superuser.com). Sorry I can't be more helpful with that :-/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a different band of wireless-N, your wi-fi may not be detected by your phone, but can be detected by your laptop. I.e. I have a dual band D-Link wireless router at home. All my laptops can detect both 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz bands, but my phone, iPod and Nook only "see" the 2.4Ghz band. 
Check your router's band to verify it matches what your phone can see (usually 2.4Ghz only).

Another thing to check in the router is security measures: you (or whoever set up the router) may have limited access or visibility, based on MAC addresses, or a manual access page.

Update:
The original question was changed after I posted my reply - which was right at the time. Should I delete it completely, or just leave it here to collect negative replies?

Comment: specially should check the  CHANNEL on the router wifi, because somethings something above 12 does not work N1

Comment: The computer is connected to the router in this setup, not the phone. The router band is irrelevant to whether the phone can connect to the computer.

Comment: The OP changed the question after  answered.